# How to check 2 strings for same numbers with single and double digits?

Tags: javascript

If I check 2 strings for same numbers and lets say i have 5 in string 1 and 15 in string 2. Then I get 5 because 5 is in 15. How can I avoid it as 5 does not equal 15 with my solution? Thanks!

```js
function FindIntersection(strArr) {
  let str1 = strArr[0].split(", ");
  let str2 = strArr[1].split(", ");
  let res = str1.filter((num) => str2.includes(num)).join(",");

  return res.length > 0 ? res : false;
}

console.log(FindIntersection(["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"]));
```

Update:
sorry I actually uploaded the wrong version and it works. What works weird is the code below:

```js
  function FindIntersection(strArr) { 
  let str1 = strArr[0];
  let str2 = strArr[1];
  let res = str1.split(", ").filter((num, index) => str2.includes(num)).join()
            return res.length > 0 ? res : false;
  }
  FindIntersection(["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"]);
console.log(FindIntersection(["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"]));
```

if input is ["1, 2, 4, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"] result is correct (1,4) (5 is not part of it)
if input is ["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"] result is wrong as I get 5

Update: I really just want to understand why the second code isnt working - why cant I use include on a string (then i get 5) and why using include on array works (here i dont get 5 = which is correct) and no other solution.Thank you

Comment: please add the result.

Comment: don't know what you are up to

Comment: Are you saying that `5` is detected to be insider `str2` because `str2` has `15`? Because I can't see this happening in the code.

Comment: Please see my update, super sorry as I uploaded wrong (working code by accident)

Comment: what is the difference between the two code blocks?

Comment: @javascripting You've pasted the same code again.

Comment: so sorry, you right. I updated

Answer (score 1):

You could split the strings and take a `Set` and filter the values.

```js
function findIntersection(array) {
    var [left, right] = array.map(s => s.split(/,\s*/).map(Number)),
        intersection = left.filter(Set.prototype.has, new Set(right));

    return intersection.length ? intersection : false;
}

console.log(findIntersection(["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"]));
console.log(findIntersection(["2, 15, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing the string comparison, We can just prepend some char to both sides and compare.

Following is minimal modifications to your almost working code

1) str2 to `strArr[1].split(", ").map(x => "-" + x).join(", ")`

2) and change compare to `str2.includes('-' + num)`

Update:

Adding alternate way using `flatMap`, `reduce`, `filter` and comma operator.

```js
function FindIntersection(strArr) {
  let str1 = strArr[0];
  let str2 = strArr[1]
    .split(", ")
    .map(x => "-" + x)
    .join(", ");
  let res = str1
    .split(", ")
    .filter((num, index) => str2.includes('-' + num))
    .join();
  return res.length > 0 ? res : false;
}

const data = ["2, 5, 7", "1, 4, 13, 15"];
const data2 = ["2, 5, 7", "5, 7, 1, 4, 13, 15"];
console.log(data, FindIntersection(data));
console.log(data2, FindIntersection(data2));

// Alternate way, Using flatMap, reduce and filter
const find = strArr => (
  (res = Object.values(
    strArr
      .flatMap(str => str.split(", "))
      .reduce((acc, num) => ((acc[num] = num in acc ? num : ""), acc), {})
  )
    .filter(num => num)
    .join(",")),
  (res.length > 0 ? res: false)
);

console.log(data, find(data));
console.log(data2, find(data2));
```

Comment: but your code also prints 5 even though 5 is not in second string

Comment: @javascripting, my data has 5 in both. Let me add more tests.